# Subclass not inheriting structure from superclass properly

Tags: python, name-mangling

I'm just starting out with Python, but I cannot  figure out why I'm having a problem with such simple class inheritance, and despite the common use of the tutorial I've been following, I haven't seen anyone else on Stack Overflow encountering this issue. Here's the code (don't worry, nothing too complicated):

```
import random
import sys
import os

class Animal:
    __name = ""
    __height = 0
    __weight = 0
    __sound = 0

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.__name = name
        self.__height = height
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__sound = sound

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and says {}".format(self.__name,
                                                                      self.__height,
                                                                      self.__weight,
                                                                      self.__sound)

cat = Animal ('Whiskers', 33, 10, 'meow')
print(cat.toString())

bird = Animal ('Flutie', 33, 10, 'tweet')
print(bird.toString())

class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and says {}".format(self.__name,
                                                                      self.__height,
                                                                      self.__weight,
                                                                      self.__sound)

spot = Dog ('Spot', 53, 27, "Woof")

print(spot.toString())
```

...And here's the output:

```
Whiskers is 33 cm tall and 10 kilograms and says meow
Flutie is 33 cm tall and 10 kilograms and says tweet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../animal_test.py", line 72, in <module>
    print(spot.toString())
  File "C:/.../animal_test.py", line 65, in toString
    return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and says {}".format(self.__name,
AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute '_Dog__name'
```

Comment: Double underscores in attribute names have a special meaning in python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name

Comment: Aside from the name mangling issues, setting `__name = ''` etc. at the class level probably doesn't do what you think, serves no purpose here, and is likely to lead to problems later.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski No, that's not relevant here.

Comment: @PM2Ring right, I've been checking that on python2 and I've got different error.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski Hopefully, the OP _isn't_ using Python2! In Python 2, `Animal` should inherit from `object`, otherwise you get the inferior old-style classes. However, in Python 3 you can call `super` without supplying args, which makes it simpler to use than in Python 2, although scary things happen internally to make that magic work. ;)

Comment: Python != Java. Stop writing double-underscore name-mangled attributes *unless that is what you want*, that, you are trying to create class-local references, which it certainly isn't what you want given that you are trying to access the attributes in a subclass. Stop writing attributes at the class level that you are only going to shadow at the instance level, i.e. `__name = ""` This almost certainly isn't doing what you think it is doing.  Don't write a `toString` method, use `__str__`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what tutorial are you following?

Comment: The tutorial I'm following is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4mEzFDjqtA, with the relevant part starting at 32 mins. I'm still perplexed why no errors flew up for him...

Comment: @PlatypusEgg I'm highly skeptical of that tutorial. Just giving it a quick look, the person has all the classic signs of someone teaching you *Java in Python*. They use parentheses around conditional statements: `if (something is something): `. They use errant semi-colons ending lines. And the example of the class definition is totally non-pythonic because of the things I mentioned above.  He also teaches you to write getters and setters, which is not the you do encapsulation in Python. They are probably coming from either Java/C++ . Get a better Python tutorial if you want to learn Python.

Comment: Good to know! I'm going with Code Academy now instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double underscores represents [name mangling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/6622817).

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.__name = name
        self.__height = height
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__sound = sound
```

Literally translates to this when being interpreted:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self._Animal__name = name
        self._Animal__height = height
        self._Animal__weight = weight
        self._Animal__sound = sound
```

It doesn’t matter where it’s called, or who called the `__init__`, the prefix `_Animal` will take place because it’s physically located under the `Animal` class.

But when you used the attributes here, as it’s physically located under the `Dog` class, the got name mangled to this:

```
class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and says {}".format(self._Dog__name,
                                                                      self._Dog__height,
                                                                      self._Dog__weight,
                                                                      self._Dog__sound)
```

Which the `Dog` object definitely doesn’t have an attribute named `self._Dog__name`, instead it has the attribute `self._Animal__name`.

Comment: Interesting. Removing the double-underscores from all the attributes made the code work, so thank you. I think I understand how the name-mangling caused the problem. I guess my only question now is why it also worked for the highly-credible tutorial I was following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4mEzFDjqtA. The class introduction stuff starts at 32 mins. He is using Python version 3.4.2...

Comment: That tutorial isn’t particularly a good one...he made the mistake but didn’t explain/catch it in the video. In his actual code, he called the getter functions instead of the underscored attributes. Ie. he did this in his actual code: `self.get_name()` instead of `self.__name()` inside the `Dog` class’s `toString` string formatting

Comment: Here’s his code: http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/11/python-programming/ , scroll down to where the Dog class is defined, note how his toString function differs from the videos’

Comment: I intend to keep watching tutorials in order to start to understand general preferences for certain methods, but if there's one you'd highly recommend for a beginner to Python (and non-markup programming in general), I'd love to know it.

Comment: I learned python by reading lots of books :D but the official python tutorial is pretty neat https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/ , and code academy has a hands-on tutorial https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python . For video tutorials, sorry I don’t have any preference...

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm working on code academy as we speak, which thankfully takes more time actually going over terminology and rationale behind Python's syntax!